# App desing: UITabBarController inside UINavigationController

Tags: ios, design-patterns, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My app has to have a launch screen where I perform some operations such as updating web content. After the process is done, I display the whole app interface within a `UITabBarController`. At some point, the app has to go back to this launch view controller to handle the update of the application data.

Apple **specifically** states that a `UITabBarController` should be the root view controller of any app.

I'm looking for clever ways of presenting a `UIViewController` before a `UITabBarController` without embedding both of them in a `UINavigationController`.

I currently have the setup I want to avoid (`UINavigationController` -> `UITabBarController`) because it works and makes sense. I'm afraid Apple wont like it, so i'm looking forward for some light in the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, nothing that I've read says that the root controller has to remain the same throughout the life of the app.  What about something like...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.tabController = (UITabBarController *)[self.window rootViewController];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self.altController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AlternateController"];
    return YES;
}

- (void)swapRootControllers {
    if ([[self.window rootViewController] isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        self.window.rootViewController = self.altController;
    } else {
        self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController;
    }
}
```

...assuming all the supporting variable declarations and storyboard implementation.

Comment: Thank you. It's really really clever. I love it.